# How do I show UI for unit Conversion appropriately?

Tags: user-expectation, intuition

I am design a software where you can import your 3d file for printing.
Now problem is when you import, it will ask you if the model was designed in MM or INCHES.

[image]

This UX is bad. When you toggle that switch from inches to mm, it will convert mm in inches and inches in mm which does not make sense at all.

I want to show a smart UI where it is not difficult for user to understand that he is printing his model desired units.

Comment: Perhaps remove the switch and make the lists selectable with a light-tone background for the selected item? The buttons should also reflect this, by setting them Accept and Cancel, or something like that. Also, a side-note: the blue 'z' is very hard to read against this background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **The text is much too wordy.** And why "We're not sure if this is the correct size?"  It sounds like something is going wrong.  I would keep it simple, like *Select unit of model:*
- **The switch only shows the selected option**, making it unclear what you are switching it to if you flip it.  You sort of have to figure this out from the rest of the dialog.  I would prefer radio buttons here, as you can see both options.
- **Show the dimensions only in the selected unit**, as JohnGB suggested.  The way of displaying the dimensions is acceptable, but it could be slicker (such as by showing a 3D box with the appropriate dimensions labeled).
- **Yes/No** make no sense. The buttons are not answering a question. I would prefer *ok/cancel*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any common use case to show both the inches and millimeters at the same time, while showing them at the same time may cause confusion.

Visuals such as colour aside, I would keep the switch and the question, but only show the "Size in inches" if the switch shows inches, and similarly for millimeters.  As an aside, I would use "inches" not "IN" on the switch, as IN isn't a standard short form for inches, and the standard short form is simply `"` which is unlikely to be clear.

The buttons should then use something more clear like `Cancel` and `Use inches` / `Use millimeters` depending on which switch has been set.  This gives a mix of maximum clarity while still maintaining expectations.

---

There are a few ways of handing the selection design wise, and I've only given one that is as close to what you have now, while still being good UX wise.  In the end, you really need to test out whatever your choice is with users to know what is right for your situation.